# Magento Top Links "Log Out" link doesn't show sometimes

Tags: magento

When I'm logged in, sometimes my "Log Out" link shows in the top links section, sometimes not.

Seems to depend on the particular session, i.e. if I close my browser and come back later it might be there. Weird I know.

This code is in my customer.xml which appears to work sometimes.

```
<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
-->

    <customer_logged_out>
        <!---<reference name="right">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
        </reference>-->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>
```

I figured something maybe overwriting it somehow later in the load chain, but I can't find any references to remove this link.

I also added this exact code to a local.xml file which should get loaded last .. no luck there.

Any thoughts on what's going on? I'm using Magento 1.6.1 community. It's seems to me this could be a bug, based on the erratic behavior pattern.

Comment: I can not see "log out", never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to post the snippet here becuase SO strips it too much, but here is your answer. 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/52285/#t263743